# x axis labels (date) slips in Python matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm beginner in Python and I have the following problems. I would like to plot a dataset, where the x-axis shows date data. The Dataset look likes the follows:

```
datum, start, end  
2017.09.01  38086   37719,8984  
2017.09.04  37707.3906  37465.2617   
2017.09.05  37471.5117  37736.1016  
2017.09.06  37723.5898  37878.8594  
2017.09.07  37878.8594  37783.5117  
2017.09.08  37764.7383  37596.75  
2017.09.11  37615.5117  37895.8516  
2017.09.12  37889.6016  38076.8789  
2017.09.13  38089.1406  38119.0898  
2017.09.14  38119.2617  38243.1992  
2017.09.15  38243.7188  38325.9297  
2017.09.18  38325.3086  38387.2188  
2017.09.19  38387.2188  38176.0781  
2017.09.20  38173.2109  38108.0391  
2017.09.21  38107.2617  38109.2109  
2017.09.22  38110.4609  38178.6289  
2017.09.25  38121.9102  38107.8711  
2017.09.26  38127.25    37319.2383  
2017.09.27  37360.8398  37244.3008  
2017.09.28  37282.1094  37191.6484  
2017.09.29  37192.1484  37290.6484
```

In the first column are the labels of the x-axis (this is the date).

When I write the following code the x axis data slips:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bux = pd.read_csv('C:\\Home\\BUX.txt', 
               sep='\t',
               decimal='.',
               header=0)
fig1 = bux.plot(marker='o')
fig1.set_xticklabels(bux.datum, rotation='vertical', fontsize=8)
```

The resulted figure look likes as follows:

[image: resulted figure]

The second data row in the dataset is '2017.09.04 37707.3906 37465.2617', BUT '2017.09.04' is yield at the third data row with start value=37471.5117

What shell I do to get correct x axis labels?

Thank you!
Agnes

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a comma in the second line instead of a `.`. This should be adjusted. Then, you convert the "datum," column to actual dates and simply plot the dataframe with matplotlib.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data/BUX.txt',  sep='\s+')
df["datum,"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datum,"], format="%Y.%m.%d")

plt.plot(df["datum,"], df["start,"], marker="o")
plt.plot(df["datum,"], df["end"], marker="o")
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! It works perfectly. The key moment was to convert the data to date format. Thank you again!

Agnes

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can easily use the `df.plot()` to fix it:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
t="""
date        start       end
2017.09.01  38086       37719.8984  
2017.09.04  37707.3906  37465.2617   
2017.09.05  37471.5117  37736.1016  
2017.09.06  37723.5898  37878.8594  
2017.09.07  37878.8594  37783.5117  
2017.09.08  37764.7383  37596.75  
2017.09.11  37615.5117  37895.8516  
2017.09.12  37889.6016  38076.8789  
2017.09.13  38089.1406  38119.0898  
2017.09.14  38119.2617  38243.1992  
2017.09.15  38243.7188  38325.9297  
2017.09.18  38325.3086  38387.2188  
2017.09.19  38387.2188  38176.0781  
2017.09.20  38173.2109  38108.0391  
2017.09.21  38107.2617  38109.2109  
2017.09.22  38110.4609  38178.6289  
2017.09.25  38121.9102  38107.8711  
2017.09.26  38127.25    37319.2383  
2017.09.27  37360.8398  37244.3008  
2017.09.28  37282.1094  37191.6484  
2017.09.29  37192.1484  37290.6484
"""
import numpy as np

data=pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(t),header=1,parse_dates=['date'])
data.plot(x='date',marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image]